# AS2: removeMovieClip() not working

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

So I duplicate a `MovieClip` that is on the Stage and created through the IDE like so:

```
duplicateMovieClip(timeData, "nextTimeData", timeData._parent.getNextHighestDepth());
```

This works great, but when I go to delete the `MovieClip` like so:

```
trace(timeData);
removeMovieClip(timeData);
trace(timeData);
trace(nextTimeData);
```

It refuses to be deleted and `trace(timeData)` outputs `_level0.timeData` before and after `removeMovieClip(timeData)`

Why would this be happening?

**EDIT:** According to the answers and the flash documentation MovieClips created in the IDE have a negative depth and `removeMovieClip()` silently fails in removing MovieClips with a negative depth.

So I am now attaching `timeData` from the library like so:

```
attachMovie("timeData", "timeData", this.getNextHighestDepth());
timeData._x = 530;
timeData._y = 492.5;
```

However it is showing the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove a MovieClip that you created by hand from the IDE using `removeMovieClip()`:

> Removes a movie clip instance created with duplicateMovieClip(), MovieClip.duplicateMovieClip(), MovieClip.createEmptyMovieClip(), or MovieClip.attachMovie().

From http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001349.html

You could remove `nextTimeData` this way, but you'll never be able to remove `timeData` unless you create it from AS as well.

Comment: I have now removed it from the IDE and am attaching it via `attachMovie()`, it has exactly the same behaviour as before.

Comment: Yes you CAN remove it even if it was placed on the stage in the IDE, check out my answer.

Comment: My bad for trusting the docs, then. I'll take your word for it. I'd love to verify that, but my Flash CC won't event allow me to create an AS2 file.. I think that says a lot..

Answer (score 3):

YES, there is a way:

in the IDE click on the MovieClip instance, and put this code in the AS panel:

```
onClipEvent(load)
{
    this.swapDepths(0);
    this.removeMovieClip();
}
```

to be able to use `removeMovieClip()` on an instance it needs to have a proper depth, that's why you need to set the depth first. Bang, magic :)

Of course you can use this code and alter it, so you can control this movieClip from other instances or timelines.

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: I don't quite understand why the down vote, but it makes sense accepting a "No, you can't do it" solutions rather than a working one makes total sense right?

Comment: This is the correct answer, the documentation is contradictory. It specifically mentions you can swap depths to delete IDE items, right after it states you cant delete them.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you created your movieclip using the IDE (Flash environment).

NOTE:  Movieclips created using the IDE actually have negative depths by default.

removeMovieClip will only remove clips at positive depths.

If you want to delete your movieclip that you positioned using the IDE, you'll need to first use swapDepths to bring your movieclip into "positive" depths.  After that, you should be able to remove it no problem.

Answer (score -1):

In AS2 object created through IDE cannot be removed by removeMovieClip. That's said in official as2 help. But duplicated one can be removed with this function. You'd better take your timeData from the library using code, not manually

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question because this didn't quite solve it =/